# Which encoding is required by unixODBC for SQLWCHAR?

Tags: sqlite, unicode, odbc, unixodbc

UnixODBC's SQLWCHAR type is a unsigned short int, matching the size of the wchar_t type on Windows. I assume that the encoding must be UCS2, but a quick test application using the SQLite ODBC driver failed.
If I call SQLExecDirectW() with a UCS2 string like "INSERT INTO foo(name) VALUES('ä')", the value 0xE4 is stored (which is the correct UCS2 value, but it should be stored as UTF-8 (0xC3A4)).

If I convert the UCS2 string to an UTF-8 string in the first step and then writing each byte (!) into a SQLWCHAR array, the SQLExecDirectW() call insert the correct value into the database.
But packing a UTF-8 (1-Byte sequence) into a 2-Byte sequence (still containing UTF-8) seems absolutely wrong to me.

**Just a hint:**

with pyodbc on pyhton3 (which used the Wide-API, too), the same problem appears:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bla VALUES('ä')")
```

This results in:

```
sqlite> select hex(id), id from bla;
E4|�
```

Comment: Are you sure the SQLite ODBC driver supports the wide APIs. If it does not then the unixODBC driver manager will quietly strip the top byte from your UCS2 SQLWCHARs and pass then to the ansi API i.e., you call SQLExecDirectW and SQLite ODBC does not have it, unixODBC calls SQLExecDirectA. I don't use SQLite ODBC driver myself just something to check on.

Comment: The SQLite driver for Linux only provides the ANSI functions. But afaik the driver manager must convert the wide string from the application to ANSI strings for the driver. On Windows, this conversion uses the Windows Code Page for the ANSI charset, I assume for Linux the behavior should be similar (instead of just stripping the top byte). Just stripping would make the whole ODBC 'design' totally broken.

Comment: It is a long (10 years) shot but, was there a solution to this .?